# Add an image in another image

Tags: python, image, insert

I want to insert an image in another image, I have been able to do so using, per example, `img=open('logo.png')` as inserted image and background image `background=open('backgroundImg.png')` but when I want to work with askopenfilename I get this error :

```
background.paste(img, offset)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'paste'
```

This is my code :

```
from PIL import Image
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import cv2

filename1 = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")])
filename2 = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")])
img=cv2.imread(filename1,1)
background=cv2.imread(filename2,1)
img_w, img_h =img.shape[:2]
bg_w, bg_h = background.shape[:2]
offset = ((bg_w - img_w) // 2, (bg_h - img_h) // 2)
background.paste(img, offset)
background.save('savedImg/out6.png')
```

any help will be appreciated
Thank u ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply overwrite the values of your image with the values of your logo. Your image is a WxHx3 array, and your logo is W1xH1x3, assuming W < W1 and H < H1. Having said that, you can simply:

```
background[offset[0]:offset[0]+img_w,offset[1]:offset[1]+img_h] = img
```

A simple test:

```
import cv2
import numpy
background = numpy.zeros((100,100,3))
img = numpy.ones((10,10,3))
offset = numpy.array((10,10))
background[offset[0]:offset[0]+img.shape[0],offset[1]:offset[1]+img.shape[1]] = img
cv2.imshow("test", background)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank u
I tried to test ur solution but I got an error :
     `background[offset[0]:offset[0]+img.shape[0]] 
     [offset[1]:offset[1]+img.shape[1]] = img`

    `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,10,3) 
    into shape (0,100,3) `

Comment: Yeah you're right, fixed the typo. Try the code provided again.

Comment: Thank u for ur help ^^